# Django: proper way to handle form with POST to the same page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django and have completed the 7 part tutorial on their website. [Part four](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/) of their tutorial introduces a form on the page `details` which posts to `votes` (a view that does not display anything) and then returns `results` on success or otherwise returns you to `details`.

However, what if you had a page that you wanted to POST to itself (e.g. updating the value of something related to that page, which is calculated server side).

Note: I have gotten this to work, but I would like to know if I am doing it right for I am confused about a few things.

So the code for my page currently looks something like:

```
def post_to_self_page(request, object_id):

    obj = get_object_or_404(Obj, pk=object_id)

    # if update sent, change the model and save it
    model_updated = False
    if 'attribute_of_obj' in request.POST.keys():
        obj.attribute_of_obj = request.POST['attribute_of_obj']
        obj.save()
        model_updated = True

    # do some stuff with obj

    # specify the context
    context = {
    'obj': obj,
    }
    if model_updated:
        # good web practice when posting to use redirect
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_app:post_to_self_page', args=(object_id,)))
    return render(request, 'my_app/post_to_self_page.html', context)
```

so in this case when the view is first called I grab the object if it exists. Then I check to see if any attributes are in the POST: if so, I update the model. Then if the model was updated I use HttpResponseRedirect to the same page, otherwise I send just use render (first call)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
def post_to_self_page(request, object_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Obj, pk=object_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj.attribute_of_obj = request.POST['attribute_of_obj'] 
        obj.save() 
    context = { 'obj': obj, }
    return render(request, 'my_app/post_to_self_page.html', context)
```