# Django: maintaining server side data whilst obtaining POST request?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django and now that I have complete the 7 part tutorial I am trying to learn more while making my own application.

One part of my application takes input from the user and then requires some non-trivial server-side calculation (e.g. the user will experience some wait) before producing the output. So instead of calculating everything all at once, I would like to have several small forms, each sending data to the server calculating part and waiting until it receives the next. For example:

> **my_app**: will have a form which asks the user for three numbers, it will subtract the first from 100, then add the second number to the result, and finally multiply the new result by the third input:
>
> e.g.
>
> my form
>
> 1st: 5
>
> 2ed: 7
>
> 3rd: 2
>
> result: (((100 - 5) + 7) * 2) = 204

While the above example is trivial, what I am doing will take some time (but, if it is not the first field, is dependent on the results from the previous result).

I learned how to properly have a view post to itself here:
[Django: proper way to handle form with POST to the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356091/django-proper-way-to-handle-form-with-post-to-the-same-page)

So how can I have this serial calculation happen as the user enters the data for each part of the form? (and wait until the previous result is calculated or until the user posts the next information before continuing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer would be "stash the responses in sessions". So something like this:

question1.py

```
if form.is_valid():
    request.session['height'] = height_calc(form.cleaned_data['height'])
```

question2.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    request.session['weight'] = weight_calc(request.session['height'], 
                                            form.cleaned_data['weight'])
```

question3.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # now we have everything so do the final calculation
    final_result = final_calc(request.session['height'],
                              request.session['weight'],
                              form.cleaned_data['favorite_color'])
```

Comment: All that in the same view? How would you handle the possible race condition of `weight` being submitted before the function `height_calc` resolved? Could you maybe also post a dummy view for handling the form that posts to itself just to make sure I fully understand

Comment: No, those are three different views.

Comment: @SumNeuron : I was trying to emphasize the use of the session to store information (and I'm assuming that you know the default pattern for handling Django forms). Any additional logic (like handling race conditions) is up to you.

Comment: @ChrisCurvey this throws an error `TypeError: my_object is not JSON serializable`... I also tried `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(my_app:form_part_2, args=()))` with a view `form_part_2(request, my_object)` but that doesnt work... is there a way to pass arguments to another view with `HttpResponseRedirect` where the arguments are not part of the `url`?

Comment: you have unlocked the next issue! congratulations!  Django is trying to serialize "my_object", but can't do it with the default serializer.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization and use the PickleSerializer instead (after reading the security warning)